# Android widget asynctask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-widget

I have an android app with widget which should parse some rss and get some data.
Here is my onReceive method:

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context,intent);
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_TOAST)) {           
            new RetrieveTask().execute(context); 
           }

    }
```

And async method itself:

```
    class RetrieveTask extends  AsyncTask<Context,Void, List<String>> {
    private Exception exception;
    private Context context;
    private RemoteViews views;

    @Override
    protected List<String> doInBackground(Context... params) {

            List<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            int k = 15;                
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://vlg-media.ru/transport").get();

            String img = "";
            int i = 0;                
            Title = doc.select(".art_img");

            for (Element titles : Title) {
                String IMG = URL;
                String HREF;
                //Element Img = titles.select(".art_image").first();
                IMG = "http://vlg-media.ru" + titles.select("img").attr("src").toString();
                IMG = IMG.replace("small", "medium");
                HREF = "http://vlg-media.ru" + titles.select("a").attr("href").toString();
                // Element Title = titles.select(".con_titlelink").first();
                String title = titles.select("img").attr("alt").toString();

                m = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                m.put(ATTRIBUTE_NAME_TITLE, title);

                //добавление данных в наш контейнер
                data.add(m);
                publishProgress();
                i++;
                //}
                if (i == k)
                    break;
            }
            //}
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            this.exception = ex;
            return null;
        }
        return  output;
    }



    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> output) {
        //to make sure it run
        Toast.makeText(context,"Done",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

After doInBackground happens nothing. onPostExecute never run.
I just need to run async parser in my AppWidgetProvider. Don't know where is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you never assign the `Context` object. In your case is just

```
 context = params[0];
```

as first line of `doInBackground`

Comment: So, do i realy need it?
Im not sure. Is it reason why doInBackground never runs?

Comment: you said that `onPostExecute` never runs. What happens you add `@Override` in  `onPostExecute` ?